# JPanel inside JFrame and Menu not losing focus

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenubar

I have a JFrame with a `JMenuBar`, inside the JFrame there is a JPanel (the panel occupies all the space but the menu bar).  The thing is that when I have the mouse over some MenuItem and move the mouse to the JPanel and do click, the menu should retract (I mean when you select in a menu for ex. File, it shows the submenu and when you move the mouse to another place of the window and do click the submenu hides/retract).

Comment: I tried, but could not reproduce your problem. Could you perhaps show the code? Or make a quick short new JMenuBar project that has the same issue and post that code? (although, trying to reproduce an error in a small example can sometimes help to find some errors yourself)

Comment: You could be mixing heavy and light weight components...

Comment: As MadProgrammer said. I once had the same problem when using Swing and SWT togeteher. When I went from one GUI framework to the other GUI framework, no message was sent to the first framework that it no longer had focus.

Comment: A picture doesn't help us. You need to post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Sorry, it was due to the setLookAndFeel,it is solved now.
Thx to all!